# Getting Python error for raster analysis interpolation using nearest neighbor in QGIS

Tags: interpolation

I am trying to interpolate temperature values into a raster using QGIS 2.18.15 in Windows. I need the output file as a GeoTIFF (.tif) file. I have my input for temperature already in a shapefile, but whenever I try to execute the command, it shows a Python error.

These are the procedures I have taken
[image]

But it shows me this
[image]
When I click Stack trace it says this:

---

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", line 88, in onFinished
    self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
    msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.15 Las Palmas, ac2d111ed1

The message log says this:

```
2018-01-18T19:04:55 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", line 88, in onFinished
                self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
                msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
            UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What I should do?

Here is a link to my shapefile
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17At2G7yBLRxSrWhS9yhIKIJBs8R0iHd_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Change path name to include only latin characters.

Comment: A shapefile consists generally of multiple files in the file system (generally .dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx, .qpg). You need to zip all of them and provide, otherwise it is impossible to open.

Comment: My guess would be because you have non-ASCII characters in your file path (ソフト). Try saving your tif to a directory path with only ASCII characters; does it still produce this error?

Comment: Yes! I changed my file path to english and the execution went through properly! Thank you very much!